# VBA Class with Static Methods

Tags: vba, excel

VBA allows you to define class methods as static.  Despite a lot of experimentation, I cannot see how these differ from regular class methods.  I suspect there is no difference and that the engine ignores the static keyword in this context.

Here is a sample class that will compile (tested Excel 2010):

```
' Class1.
' 4 methods, 2 static & 2 not.

Public Sub Method1()

    Debug.Print "foo"
End Sub

Public Static Sub Method2()

    Debug.Print "bar"
End Sub

Public Function Method3() As String

    Method3 = "foo"
End Function

Public Static Function Method4() As String

    Method4 = "bar"
End Function
```

Tested like so:

```
Sub TestClass1()    
    Dim x As Class1
    Set x = New Class1

    x.Method1   ' prints foo.
    x.Method2   ' prints bar.
    x.Method3   ' returns foo.
    x.Method4   ' returns bar.
End Sub
```

Some observations:

- static methods are recalculated on each call.
- static methods cannot be called without first instancing the class.

Am I missing something?

Comment: To my understanding the difference is that if you change a variable in a static Sub, the variable is changed permanently. Definitely could be wrong

Comment: It doesn't appear in the list of modifiers here, in the documentation, so I imagine it is skipped.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/sub-statement

Comment: @ThatOneGuy You are correct. Any variable in a `static` routine becomes `static`, and therefore persists its value between calls to that routine, for the lifetime of the class instance.